# Garbage collection in database?

Tags: mysql, myisam

its kind weird idea which I would need suggestions. A classical example:

```
users
-----
ID | USERNAME
1    test1
2    test2
3    test3

emails
------
USER_ID | EMAIL
1         test1@email.com
2         test2@email.com
2         test3@email.com
1         test4@email.com
3         test5@email.com
3         test6@email.com
2         test7@email.com
3         test8@email.com
1         test9@email.com
```

and a select:

```
SELECT * FROM users LEFT JOIN emails ON users.ID = emails.USER_ID
```

would resuls all emails of users. So far its so good, but lets say its a very big system and we are on `MyISAM`, so no real foreignkey connectionts. I only delete a user, so all of their emails remain. Normally we would say its bad, because lots of unconnected garbages remain. But what if we wipe out them later? We can `SELECT` those unnecessary records later and a cron-task would erase them. Is it bad, crazy idea?

Comment: You run the risk of these orphaned records showing up in some reports, between the deletion of the "parent" record and the clean-up of the "children". If this either wouldn't happen because all references to `emails` would be tied to `users` such that the orphaned records wouldn't be seen, or wouldn't matter is it did happen, then from a logical standpoint this should be OK. From a performance standpoint, as recommended in the answer, test it out and see if it's acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

MyISAM is especially bad about garbage collection.  That is one of several reasons you *really should* move to InnoDB.  MyISAM will be removed in the next release.

MyISAM, more so than InnoDB, can *sometimes* benefit from `OPTIMIZE TABLE`.  That is the command for freeing up wasted space and otherwise defragmenting a table.  It is tedious and takes a long time (depending on size of table).

As already pointed out, InnoDB, with `FOREIGN KEYs`, could take care of the deleting.

I would prefer to have an API that handles the delete -- plus any cleanup that might be needed.  Built into that API could be

- Cascading delete, or
- Application code to do the delete(s), or
- A stored procedure to do the delete(s).
- A cron job "because it could take a long time to do all the deleted".

A cron job?  -- Suggest you have the app copy the deleted `userid` into a `ToBeDeleted` table.  This could be done with a simple `TRIGGER`.  Then the cron job would select one row from that table, proceed to do deletes from various other tables (`COMMITting` as it goes), and finally delete from `ToBeDeleted`.  Rinse and Repeat.

Better yet, don't make it a cron job, make it a continually running job.  (OK, add a "keep-alive" cron job to make sure it does not vanish, especially after a reboot.)  When this continual job finds nothing to do, it sleeps for, say, a minute.  Otherwise, it runs full-tilt.

Comment: if a facebook account is deleted, deleting his all of his post, pictures, etc would cost hours. So thats why a cron-job would take care of the rest.

Comment: Based on that new requirement (which you should add to your Question), I added to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If those orphaned records are a problem, you would normally force a cascading delete on the FK. If you're still using MyISAM (InnoDB has been default for awhile already), then your garbage collection idea is workable. Benchmark how long it takes on a test system first and run it off hours if possible.